# Maintain the global state when the route change in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I create a app, everything works fine, but when i move route or reload the page, the state back to the default situation, maybe i able to fix this problem using library as react-persist or found some way to put the state on the local Storage, i don't think this approach is the best way.Maybe you another alternative?

```
`store.js`
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducer/rootReducer";
const initialState = {};
export default createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

`reducer`


 import {
  REGISTER_USER,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  LOGIN_USER,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  // LOAD_USER,
  // LOAD_USER_FAIL,
  // LOGOUT_USER,
} from "../constants";

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  loading: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  error: null,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTER_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
        loading: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case LOGIN_USER:
      localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
        loading: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
   `Login`
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import { loginAction } from "../actions/loginAction";
const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  let history = useHistory();
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (data.error) {
      setMsg(data.error.msg);
      interval = setTimeout(() => {
        setMsg("");
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (data.user) {
      setMsg(data.user.msg);
      interval = setTimeout(() => {
        setMsg("");
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(interval);
    };
  }, [data]);
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginAction(state));
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  if (data.isAuthenticated) {
    history.push("/dashboard");
  }
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      <span>{msg}</span>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={state.email} />
        <input name="password" onChange={handleChange} value={state.password} />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

`register`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { registerAction } from "../actions/registerAction";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Register = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    photo: "",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (data.error) {
      setMsg(data.error);
      interval = setTimeout(() => {
        setMsg("");
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (data.user) {
      setMsg(data.user.msg);
      interval = setTimeout(() => {
        setMsg("");
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(interval);
    };
  }, [data]);
  if (data.user) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", state.name);
    formData.append("email", state.email);
    formData.append("password", state.password);
    formData.append("photo", state.photo);
    dispatch(registerAction(formData));
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const handleOnUploadFile = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, photo: e.target.files[0] });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <span>{msg}</span>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} value={state.name} />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={state.email} />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" onChange={handleChange} value={state.password} />
        <input
          name="photo"
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={handleOnUploadFile}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store a token in Local storage and pull it out and verify it upon reload. Also you should make a new action to load user from that token. States will alwayr reset to initial state on reload.
I cant see ur registerAction page but the loadUser should be something like this

```
// Load User

export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');

      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: res.data,
   
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
      payload: err.response.data,
    });
  }
};
```

/api/auth is like this

```
// @route   GET api/auth
// @desc    Get logged in user (Login)
// @access  Private
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await Planner.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    if (user.type === 'Admin') {
      res.json({ user, admin: true });
    } else {
      res.json({ user, admin: false });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

You need to use jwttoken for example as an auth middle ware
the middleware file would be like this

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  //Get token from header
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  // Check if not token
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
  }
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));

    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};
```

I have implemented a similar redux of the contact keeper project by Brad Travery
You can see the full code here am sure it will help
https://github.com/madaher-dev/contact-keeper
Enjoy